# brew install python-setuptools not working

Tags: homebrew

When I run brew install python-setuptools

I get this error:

```
Error: No available formula for python-setuptools
```

Has anyone else encountered this error before? I haven't found similar instances after googling.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is no formula called 'python-setuptools'.

You can even verify that by running `brew search python`, which shows all packages available with 'python' in the name:

```
$ brew search python
boost-python   python         python3        wxpython       zpython
homebrew/apache/mod_python      homebrew/python/python-dbus
homebrew/versions/gst-python010     homebrew/python/vpython
```

The key question that you're actually asking is how to install python & setuptools with homebrew. The answer to that question is simply:

```
$ brew install python
```